# How far can I extend the leads of this temperature sensor?

Tags: thermistor

I purchased this cigarette lighter unit that is a voltage meter, temperature sensor, and USB charger. The temperature sensor appears to be on a wire lead that comes out of the case.

I took apart the unit and its construction is very simple. I can solder to the circuit board if need be. What type of thermistor does this unit likely use? How far can I extend the leads of the temperature sensor and have the unit continue to give an accurate reading?

[image]

[image]

Comment: Are you sure it's a thermocouple and not a thermistor?  (Measure its resistance.)

Answer (score 2):

In a consumer product such as this, the "thermocouple" is "likely" to be a thermistor.  A thermistor are just a temperature sensitive resistor, so you can solder extension wires to it without any adverse effect.  Their resistance is normally in the kilo-ohm range, so don't worry about the resistance of the wires.